# Thunderbird for Mac, new messages look the same as unread messages

Tags: macos, thunderbird

I'm used to Thunderbird for Windows where new messages have a little starburst icon next to them to visually differentiate them from unread messages. Is there a hidden option to get this in the Mac version?

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the earlier non-answer, should have read *and* understood the question ;-)

Comment: No prob :)      ....

Answer (score 0):

[image: make sure read is checked in the column picker]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I apologized for. He wants to distinguish *Read* and *New* email, not *Read* and *Unread*. His screenshot clearly shows that exact column.

Comment: this is what "Read" shows i.e the "Read" column will indicate by a "sunburst" star if it is unread and no sunburst star if it is read just like on Windows Thunderbird, so my answer is correct :-)

Comment: there is also "Status" which if checked shows "New", "Read" or "Replied"

Comment: On Thunderbird/Windows, the sunburst is only shown on *new* mail, not unread mail. Unread mail is shown in bold. On the Mac, both new and unread messages appear in bold *and* have the sunburst.

Comment: ok chaiguy, i finally understand, clearly I am screenshot challenged :-) It would have been really helpful to have included this text: "On Thunderbird/Windows, the sunburst is only shown on new mail, not unread mail. Unread mail is shown in bold. On the Mac, both new and unread messages appear in bold and have the sunburst." in your original post